# books move to only two shelf not to the 3rd shelf. also event handle error

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, data-binding, event-handling

please go through my code and help me to solve my problems.

I have shared my github link below.

https://github.com/Ipsa-Pradhan/MyReads

here are the issues:

when i tried to move a book from one shelf to another, it moved but after refreshing the page. And this happens with the search page.

But when same thing i tried within the shelves in the main page it showing the below error.

TypeError: _this.props.onUpdateShelf is not a function (line no- 10)

and also i have created 3 shelfs and books are moving to two of the shelfs but not to the 3rd shelf.